# Reverse engineering of fmx file from exe (Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.2, FMX)

Tags: reverse-engineering, firemonkey

Is there a method to recreate the fmx file (form structure and components used) based on the compiled application (exe file) ?

I lost the source version of these files and need to recreate them.
I have the cpp and h files only.

I can't find any method to do it.
It will be good to get the components structure placed on a fmx form.